# UTF-8 encoding problems in Python, joining utf-8 with ascii string (interpolation actually)

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I have the following code:

```
u"[%s] - %s" % (a, b.encode('utf-8'))
```

Where `a` is a `unicode` string and b is a classical `str`

Now this gives the classical error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

(Position 2 belongs to a)

Why doesn't this work? I thought that if I make string `b` an unicode string, then it should n't have to convert to ascii when joining the strings together?

Comment: you might mean `b.decode("utf-8")`, to convert `b` bytestring to Unicode. In general, bytes -> decode() -> Unicode -> encode() -> bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was solved, basically I'm an idiot who doesn't know the difference between overloading the `__str__()` method and the `__Unicode__()` method. The whole error ocurred when everything was converted to str before it was returned from the method.

Leaving this answer here in case someone gets a similar problem and doesn't know about the `__unicode__()` magic method of classes.

Comment: I wonder where the __unicode__ is in the context of the question

Comment: It's basically like this: `def __str__(self): return u"[%s] - %s" % (a, b.encode('utf-8'))`, just replace `__str__` with `_unicode__` and everything works..